# Capturing filename with python requests toolbelt

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using python requests-toolbelt to post large audio files. I was originally using requests to post the file like so:

```
files = {'file': open("test.mp3", "rb")}
audio_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
add_file = requests.post(file_url, headers=audio_headers, files=files)
```

That successfully grabbed my file and added the filename to the filename field, but it didn't work for large files.

So I switched to posting files with the requests-toolbelt MultipartEncoder like so:

```
files = MultipartEncoder({'file': open(file, "rb")})
audio_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, 'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg'}
add_file = requests.post(file_url, headers=headers, data=files)
```

In this scenario the file is created, but the filename isn't captured.

I also tried defining files like this:

```
files = MultipartEncoder({'file': file, open(file, "rb"), 'audio/mpeg')})
```

Any idea how to successfully pass my file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to follow the example exactly...

```
files = MultipartEncoder(fields={'file': (file, open(file, "rb"), 'audio/mpeg')})
audio_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, 'Content-Type': files.content_type}
add_file = requests.post(file_url, headers=audio_headers, data=files)
```

Totally works now.

Comment: Yep, I was about to answer that =P. If there's a way to make it clearer, please send a pull request. I often spend my time working on bugs and seldom update the docs in a timely fashion. Also, having a user help with them is usually better.